# Formatting a column to a type can I have header text that is not that field type and will not cause issues?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

If I have a column of data in Google Sheets or Excel can I have a header column that is not that type?

For example, I need to have a column of data of type `time`. But I want to have a header text for that column. How would I do this?

**Update:**
I selected the column and set the format to `time`. It looks like it didn't affect my headers! Will this break anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do exactly what you did. It works nicely because you don't need something like a bold font as your header while you need not bold characters in the data cells below it. Excel happily sees the number formatting and applies it to numbers, displaying them as time. And when it sees text instead, it simply applies the "general" format to that.

Alternatively, you can format the columns to the type of format desired (they're not really "types" of the sort you kind of seem to mean). Then, when settled, change the formatting of the row with the headers in it. So you set maybe number formatting as some time format, a font of Comic Sans, 11 pt, and dark blue text. Happy with that for the values in the column, you then change the header cell for the column to be general format, still Comic Sans, but now 14 pt and bold, and automatic for font color.

The alternative approach takes a more active set of actions is all. Not needed here as you seem happy with the display results, but in many cases, you might care and need to use it.

To return to the "type" concerns, nothing about what you did will itself cause any problems for you. You can end up with problems, but they'll be of the kind in which you have formulas that use the text of the header in them and choke on the text because they had to have a number. Used to be (long time ago, not even sure when it changed) that summing a range of cells that had a text entry gave an error. Another thing would be a formula that looks at the cell of interest and subtracts (say) the cell above it, then compares the result to something. When it is in row 2, it will subtract row 1, that header text. Likely will choke (again, it used to, and I assume it still does). Those kinds of things. But those are construction mistakes that fail because of the content of the cell, not the formatting of the cell. There are some even more subtle, much more subtle. Just don't use the header cell in formulas and no problems arise. Yes, it may be harder to write them then, but such is the price of having the headers which would fail the formulas even with precisely the same formatting as the cells below them. The content matters, not the formatting.

Because Excel does not do "types"... that is a programming thing not an Excel thing. Basically, programming languages solve a problem with typing and Excel solves it a very different way. Nothing more than that, but it means it just isn't an issue at all in Excel.